# Getting error while downloading g++ compiler on my Windows

Tags: c++

I followed all the basic standard procedures that available on the internet to installation g++ compiler on my Windows 10. 
I selected all the basic packages and applied the changes but in the middle of the installation process, it started throwing this error...

[image]

Can someone help me with what to do about this error/bug?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it only with the `libmagic` package or is it with every package?

Comment: Only with this package.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might have occured because the package was corrupted during transfer. You can manually try to download it from [here](https://github.com/jonasstrandstedt/MinGW/blob/master/MinGW/var/cache/mingw-get/packages/libmagic-5.04-1-msys-1.0.13-dll-1.tar.lzma) and then extract it in your `mingw` folder.